# DNS resolution of instances' private hostnames with OpenVPN on EC2

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, openvpn

The end goal of my setup is to for `EC2 instance hostnames` to be resolvable on the VPN clients, in addition to any `private R53` entries.

I have a working OpenVPN server config (connections are successful), except that the clients have no internet access (because DNS server is unreachable).

I also cannot `telnet` to other instances on the VPC in the same public subnet using their `private IP's`.

Re DNS: I'm unsure of which DNS server to use.  As you will see below I am pushing the default VPC DNS Server that's in the instance's `resolve.conf` file.

My VPC config is very basic:

```
VPC 172.33.0.0/16
1 Internet Gateway
1 Public Subnet
1 OpenVPN EC2 instance in Public Subnet
1 Test EC2 instance in Public Subnet (unreachable from client)
* ALLOW ACL Rules
```

I wanted to give the server a subnet within the VPC.  I chose `172.33.30.0` and I hope to route from the `tun` on the server to other EC2 instances on the VPC.

My OpenVPN `server.conf` is

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca /etc/openvpn/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/server.key
dh dh1024.pem
server 172.33.30.0 255.255.255.0
comp-lzo
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3

route 172.33.0.0. 255.255.0.0 172.33.30.1
push "route 172.33.0.0. 255.255.0.0 172.33.30.1"
push "dhcp-option DOMAIN us-west-2.compute.internal"
push "dhcp-option DNS 172.33.0.2"
```

As you can see I believe there's a problem in my `server.conf`'s routing. Any suggestions?